# Refresh Container View holding UITableView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've `View Controller` which has a `Container View` , and the `Container View` is holding inside a `UITableView`.so the main class for `View Controller` which is `MainViewController` and the class for `UITableView` is `TableViewController`

What i have here is that i need to refresh `UITableView` in the `MainViewController`.
I've found this code in objective-c but i tried converting it into swift but it didn't work :

```
UITableViewController *tbc = (UITableViewController *)self.childViewControllers[0];
[tbc.tableView reloadData];
```

Swift code i tried but it didn't work:

```
  var tv : TableViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! TableViewController
    tv.myTableView.reloadData()
```

The error I'm getting is this :

```
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1950dc0b0) to 'myapp. TableViewController' (0x10021c470).
```

Comment: in the objc code you use index 0 and in the swift code you use index 2. is that on purpose? what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @giorashc, i put it on purpose [2] because I've 2 other counter views .. anyway I've edited my question :)

Comment: it seems like that viewcontroller returned is a navigation controller and not a tableviewcontroller so the forced casting fails. Are you sure you are using the right index? (regardless of the objc code)

Comment: ah ! i did use navigation controller between ContainerView and TableViewController ! what am i suppose to do ?

Comment: Print this. println(self.childViewControllers). You will get to know where exactly your tableview controller is. The view controller hierarchy. It seems navigation controller is there in between.

Comment: so if the table view is contained in navigation controller use: navigationController.topViewController to reach the table view controller (navigationController is referencing the first view controller at index 0)

Comment: @giorashc, I've wrote like this but its giving me an error `= self.navigationController?.topViewController(0)`

Comment: @Amit89 , when i print it it shows this `[<UINavigationController: 0x14c6183f0>, <UINavigationController: 0x14c61fdd0>, <UINavigationController: 0x14c522fb0>` because there is NavigationController between ContainerView and UITableView !

Comment: topViewController is a property not a method, If you are sure that navigation controller top view controller is table view controller do like this. self.navigationController?.topViewController

Comment: I've deleted NavigationControllers and connect it directly but its not refreshing TableView !! I've wrote :     `var myv : TableViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! TableViewController
    myv.mytableview.reloadData()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my `MainViewController` I've wrote this and also by calling `viewWillAppear` it force TableView to reload :

```
var tv : TableViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! TableViewController 
tv.mytableview.reloadData()
tv.viewWillAppear(true)
```

Thanks to everyone who helped

Comment: are you sure that reloadData have to do any thing with your solution. remove it and try.

Comment: tv.viewWillAppear(true) helped me. i was doing data refetch in viewwillappear. So, calling reloadData without calling viewwillappear was useless